# I accepted an interview somewhere I don't want to work at due to location, and just realized. How do I cancel it?

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, location

I mean, how do I word the email so it doesn't look too ridiculous? Any ideas?

This office is in my area so I just assumed it's in my city, where I can get anywhere easily with public transport. Turns out it's actually in a town nearby.

I could of course get a car if I get the job, but I'd much rather work in the city and I don't think it'll be hard to get an offer here as there's a lot of opportunities. So I thought I'd turn this down. I think it'll look awful though and I don't want to burn any bridges, so, any idea how to word it?

Comment: Related / duplicate: [Made a mistake in accepting interview invitation, should I cancel?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/74678) The wording you use here isn't all that important (but, as always, try to avoid saying anything particularly negative).

Comment: This happens to me repeatedly. I'm different as I don't want to work in the city that I live. The driving traffic is insane. That's why I live beside a train station. People constantly phone me for interviews near by. The key here is to ask questions about location before you schedule the interview, and be specific. Is this where I will actually work? Image how bad it looks for a recruiter if you cancel an interview because of location. I know, I've don't this and it's unfair to them. They have to phone a person they might not be in good relationships with and explain why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, don’t do this by email. It should be done by phone so there is no delay or chance it won’t go through. And it’s a more mature way to deliver bad news. (If they have only corresponded with you by email, then an email response s is fine. But if you have a phone contact, you should use it.)

Simply explain that you have decided that you’re not going to go forward with the interviewing process with them. When they ask for a reason, you can tell them why: the commute is undesirable.

They’ll understand.

Comment: Fair point. Done!

Comment: And doing it early is better. They will be able to inform the interviewers, and perhaps schedule other candidates at a better time or free up the interviewers to do their daily work. Letting them know is not something that should be delayed.

Comment: Hey man just wanted to say thanks again for the tip. They actually called a bit later to offer the possibility of working remote, so I'll still do the interview. And I think the fact that I called to explain it over the phone and apologized may have something to do with it :)

Comment: @MockingOdist I am very happy it seems to be working out for you. The fact is, they may not have consciously thought, "Hey, MockingDist called us, that's impressive." But the fact that you have spoken with them over the phone makes you more of a real person, and people like working with real people. :) Best of luck with the rest of the process!

Answer (score -4):

If you are already in the process with that company, it means that commute was already considered by you, would look unprofessionally if you back off now for that reason.

You should communicate as soon as possible with them by the same means you did before, but say that you received an offer from closer located position and letting them know you will continue with that offer.

This way you do let them know about your issue with location but not with company.

Comment: Do you think OP should put himself at the disadvantage, that he didn`t check the location of the company he applies to?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere In the end I called and told them I didn't realize the location and apologized. They offered the possibility of working remote so it mustn't have been so bad :)

Comment: Great outcome. Congrats